# Apache beam python fileio.WriteToFiles oversharding

Tags: python, apache-beam-io, apache-beam

I'm using [`fileio.WriteToFiles`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.24.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html?highlight=writetofiles#module-apache_beam.io.fileio) in a streaming python pipeline. I explicitly specified an expected shard count as follows

```
fileio.WriteToFiles(
      path=...,
      file_naming=fileio.default_file_naming(prefix="output", suffix=".txt"),
      shards=5)
```

However, the pipeline seems to have completely ignored that shard count. Note that the streaming pipeline applies a fixed window of 30 minutes. Within each window, the output files are over-sharded as follows

```
output-2020-12-14T23:30:00-2020-12-15T00:00:00--00000-00420
output-2020-12-14T23:30:00-2020-12-15T00:00:00--00001-00420
...
output-2020-12-14T23:30:00-2020-12-15T00:00:00--00419-00420
output-2020-12-15T00:00:00-2020-12-15T00:30:00--00000-00915
output-2020-12-15T00:00:00-2020-12-15T00:30:00--00001-00915
...
output-2020-12-15T00:00:00-2020-12-15T00:30:00--00914-00915
```

After inspection, I observed that each file contains exactly one record.

I played with different triggers and `max_writers_per_bundle`, which didn't help to change this behavior.

I wonder whether this is an SDK bug or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Seems there is a JIRA raised as below similar to your issue.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-10596

Comment: Thank you. The JIRA ticket seems more about an issue with local runner and it is likely with a batch pipeline. The issue I described here is specific to streaming pipeline and it happens with Google dataflow runner.